# Unresolved reference: Matchers

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, hamcrest

I am unable to run the unit test when I import `org.hamcrest.Matchers` as I need `lessThan()`. My instrumentation tests compile properly while using the `greaterThan` matcher but not the unit tests

Code:

```
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.lessThan
import org.junit.Assert.assertThat
import org.junit.Test
import java.util.*
```

Gradle Logs: https://pastebin.com/ibgzzrg1

Removing the 2nd line makes the project compile and runs the test.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I received a compiler error "Unresolved reference: Matchers" while running the Task :compileTestKotlin. It turned out that I had declared the hamcrest dependency as **testRuntimeOnly**. Changing it to **testImplementation** fixed the issue.

```
testImplementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2")
```

It is interesting to check out the documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html).

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue.  What I was finding was that I was only experiencing this issue with *instrumented* tests.  Non-instrumented tests were able to import and run fine.

What fixed this for me was adding `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'` to my dependencies.

I had removed this thinking it wasn't necessary, since none of my tests explicitly use Espresso.  Turns out it is, for reasons beyond my understanding.

Comment: I have `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'` but the error still exist